# Any way to unlock old Samsung laptop BIOS?

Tags: bios

I got an older laptop, which has a locked BIOS. There is no windows installed. Are there any ways to reset bios, so I can go in and change boot device?

I tried multiple reset password generators but without any success.

The code on entering password wrong multiple times:

Any suggestions what else can be done?

EDIT: Laptop model is Samsung NP535U3C.

[Screenshot of error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58wkU.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried re-flashing the BIOS, or is this the default state of the BIOS?

Comment: No, I haven't tried re'flashin BIOS. Is there any way of identifying it without having access to the interface?

Comment: Not as far as I know unless the board manufacturer has software to do that. Lenovo has Diagnostic Software to do that

Answer (score 0):

There is not likely any way to bypass this (95% or greater).

Vendors fixed Laptop BIOS passwords more than 10 years ago.

So, short of asking Samsung for paid support, there is no way to change the boot order.

You can try reinstalling Windows with the Samsung Recover USB.  That might work in this case.